# Validate if all radio button groups are checked

Tags: jquery, html

I took the edit from this SF link: [StackOverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10706925/jquery-ensuring-all-radio-groups-are-checked), where user Blazemonger showed a demo in, [JFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/aVVW9/6/)

From the above:
1) How do I show all the error(s), not just one at a time, in a DIV statement below the submit button instead of the alert box?
2) How do i change the bg color back to white once the error is correct and the submit button is pressed again?

I edited the fiddle like this for Question 2, which is not working:

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    var submitme = true;
    $(':radio').each(function() {
        nam = $(this).attr('name');
        if (submitme && !$(':radio[name="'+nam+'"]:checked').length) {
            alert(nam+' group not checked');
            $(':radio[name="'+nam+'"]+label').addClass('error');
            submitme = false;
        }
        if (submitme && $(':radio[name="'+nam+'"]:checked').length <> 0) {
                $(':radio[name="'+nam+'"]+label').addClass('noerror');
        }
    });
    return submitme;
});
```

CSS:

```
.error {
    background-color: red;
}
.noerror {
    background-color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the click of the button you can check if one value in each group is selected and if not display a div ..

Check this [UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aVVW9/18/)

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    var html = '';
    var submitme = true;
    $(':radio').each(function() {
        nam = $(this).attr('name');
        if (!$(':radio[name="'+nam+'"]:checked').length) {
            $(':radio[name="'+nam+'"]+label').addClass('error');
            if(html.indexOf(nam) < 0){
                html += nam +' group not checked' + '</br>';
            }
            submitme = false;
        }
    });
    if(submitme == false){
       $('.errorDiv').empty().append(html).show().addClass('error');
    }
    else{
      $('.errorDiv').hide();
    }

    return submitme;
});
​
        ​
        .error {
            background-color: red;
            display:none;
        }
```

​

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle. How can I also change the text color of the unchecked radio group to RED along with your error div? And it only lists one group and not both if left unchecked?

Comment: Just add this line $(':radio[name="'+nam+'"]+label').addClass('error');

Comment: I updated the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aVVW9/14/ 1) if you leave both unchecked and press submit it changes text color only for the first group, not all (maybe we need a for statement?) 2) The error DIV shows one error at a time, if you leave both unchecked, the error shows the first not both.  3) When I check the first group and leave the second group empty, shouldn't it change the text back to black for the corrected error?

Comment: Check the Updated fiddle above.. Need to remove submitme &&  in the if statement

Comment: Sorry one more request, I want one error message per group. How would it be incorporated?

Comment: Check the fiddle and code above.. Just add this condition if(html.indexOf(nam) < 0){

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aVVW9/19/ .... Everything is working fine. thank you. the correct response should change back to default... i am thinking.